# How to redefine a csc function to display cosec?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I need help to define the csc function to display as cosec. I've tried `\textrm{cosec} \theta`, but this does not give the same output as `\sin \theta`, because the space between the theta and the function is closer for cosec.

Any other better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
James

Comment: `\operatorname{cosec}` (requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

Comment: Declare a new maths function with `\DeclareMathOperator{\cosec}{cosec}` .

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to redeclare this. Can you give me a code of how this can be done? I already use the amsmath package. Thanks.

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks. I got it.